# Как верстаются подобные элементы в макетах

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как правильно верстать такой блок, что бы при изменении размера в меньшую сторону, ничего не съезжало. Под конкретное разрешение понятно, что изображение по центру, а его описание через абсолютное позиционирование расставить. Но в таком случае, если уменьшать разрешение и картинка начнет уменьшатся, то всё съедет. Макет учебный и есть экраны для fullhd и мобилок. А как должны выглядеть промежуточные результаты не ясно. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно гридами реализовать, так разве что линии сносок могут вызвать проблемы. или можно забить на всё и включить *god mode*... тьфу... сверстать на svg

Answer (score 0):

Скажу за себя, не ручаюсь что это верный путь решения такого кейса. Сам столкнулся только 1 раз, решил следующим образом: много `@media` запросов и постоянная коррекция `top` и `left` у `absolute` элементов. Да, это ужасно нудно, муторно и долго, но это привело к результату, который требовался.